# problem with add_size_image

Tags: images

why if im add size like :

```
add_image_size( 'featured1', 466, 316, false);
add_image_size( 'featured2', 466, 260, false);
```

the seconde size Does not generated

What is the problem ?

Comment: Did yo uploaded image after you setup image sizes?

Comment: @Sisir yes of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because your sizes both have the same width, and you have it set to "proportional crop", which won't necessarily crop to your *exact* dimensions. ([See the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size))

In all likelihood, it *is* actually creating both images--but they're both the exact same size, so one overwrites the other :)

Try changing the last param to "true".

```
add_image_size( 'featured1', 466, 316, true);
add_image_size( 'featured2', 466, 260, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

[This is a known bug](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17626). The problem is that you have one of the dimensions *exactly the same* for both intermediate sizes.

I submitted a patch about a year ago; just waiting for it to make its way into core. It got punted to "future release".